# Read 1, 8 or 24 bits BMP File with C++

Tags: c++, c++11, bmp

I want to read-write a BMP image using c++, when I use my class with 24 bit image works but when I use a 8 bits image doesn't work (paint can't open the file), similar with 1 bit image.

I open a bmp file using "Open" function then I save this (and their headers) using "Save" function (I just copy it). The result file only open if the file is 24bit bmp file. I don't create any header, I copy the header from the source using Open function

The code I use is (see Load and Save functions):

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct FILEHEADER
{
    WORD bfType;
    DWORD bfSize;
    WORD bfReserved1;
    WORD bfReserved2;
    DWORD bOffBits;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct INFOHEADER
{
    DWORD biSize;
    LONG biWidth;
    LONG biHeight;
    WORD biPlanes;
    WORD biBitCount;
    DWORD biCompression;
    DWORD biSizeImage;
    LONG biXPelsPerMeter;
    LONG biYPelsPerMeter;
    DWORD biClrUsed;
    DWORD biClrImportant;
};
typedef INFOHEADER infoheader;
typedef FILEHEADER fileheader;

const WORD BMP_FORMAT = 0x4D42;

class Bitmap2
{
private:
    BYTE *data;
    infoheader h_info;
    fileheader h_file;

    WORD Type();
    DWORD OffBits();
    DWORD ImageSize();
    LONG Rows();
    LONG Cols();
    WORD BitsPerPixel();
    DWORD SizeInBytes();
public:
    void Load(char *filename);
    void Save(char *filename);
    void PrintHeaders();
};

void Bitmap2::Load(char *filename)
{
    std::ifstream file;

    file.open(filename, std::fstream::binary);
    if (!file.is_open())
        return;

    file.read((char *)&(h_file), sizeof(fileheader));

    //
    if (Type() != BMP_FORMAT)
    {
        file.close();
        return;
    }

    file.read((char *)&h_info, sizeof(infoheader));

    //
    file.seekg(OffBits());

    data = new BYTE[SizeInBytes()];

    if (!data)
    {
        delete data;
        file.close();
        return;
    }

    file.read((char *)data, SizeInBytes());

    if (data == NULL)
    {
        file.close();
        return;
    }

    file.close();
}

void Bitmap2::Save(char *filename)
{
    std::ofstream file;

    if (!data)
        return;

    file.open(filename, std::fstream::binary);
    if (!file.is_open())
        return;

    file.write((char *)&(h_file), sizeof(fileheader));

    //
    if (Type() != BMP_FORMAT)
    {
        file.close();
        return;
    }

    file.write((char *)&h_info, sizeof(infoheader));

    file.write((char *)data, SizeInBytes());

    file.close();
}

void Bitmap2::PrintHeaders()
{
    std::cout << "biSize = "            << h_info.biSize            << std::endl;
    std::cout << "biWidth = "           << h_info.biWidth           << std::endl;
    std::cout << "biHeight = "          << h_info.biHeight          << std::endl;
    std::cout << "biPlanes = "          << h_info.biPlanes          << std::endl;
    std::cout << "biBitCount = "        << h_info.biBitCount        << std::endl;
    std::cout << "biCompression = "     << h_info.biCompression     << std::endl;
    std::cout << "biSizeImage = "       << h_info.biSizeImage       << std::endl;
    std::cout << "biXPelsPerMeter = "   << h_info.biXPelsPerMeter   << std::endl;
    std::cout << "biYPelsPerMeter = "   << h_info.biYPelsPerMeter   << std::endl;
    std::cout << "biClrUsed = "         << h_info.biClrUsed         << std::endl;
    std::cout << "biClrImportant = "    << h_info.biClrImportant    << std::endl;
}

WORD Bitmap2::Type()
{
    return h_file.bfType;
}

DWORD Bitmap2::OffBits()
{
    return h_file.bOffBits;
}

DWORD Bitmap2::ImageSize()
{
    return h_info.biSizeImage;
}

LONG Bitmap2::Rows()
{
    return h_info.biHeight;
}

LONG Bitmap2::Cols()
{
    return h_info.biWidth;
}
WORD Bitmap2::BitsPerPixel()
{
    return h_info.biBitCount;
}
DWORD Bitmap2::SizeInBytes()
{
    return h_info.biSizeImage;
}

int main()
{
    Bitmap2 x;

    x.Load("test.bmp");
    x.Save("test_o.bmp");
    x.PrintHeaders();
    std::cout << "__________" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean ' doesn't work (paint can't open the file)'?

Comment: Please add more information. If saving an 8-bit image is your problem then please - at least - add the code which creates the header information.

Comment: I open a bmp file using "Open" function then I save this (and their headers) using "Save" function (I just copy it). The result file only open if the file is 24bit bmp file. I don't create any header, I copy the header from the source using Open function.

Answer (score 2):

[`biSizeImage` may be 0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx), in which case you have to compute the actual size.

Also, I don't see where you're reading and writing the [color table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Color_table) (palette).  Since 1- and 8-bit bitmap files require a palette and 24-bit ones don't, I suspect that's your root problem.